# How do I ensure that an image is fluid and will resize?

Tags: image, fluid-layout

I am trying to use CSS to ensure an image on my page will resize if the screen is below a certain resolution or the window below a certain size. I have read to use {max-width:100%}, which I have incorporated into my code, but the image isn't resizing at all. The image is 500px wide.

Thank you!

CSS and HTML:

```
.left{
float:left;
width:600px;
}

.right{
float:right;
width:400px;
}

#logoimage{
width: 100%;
margin: 50px auto;
max-width: 100%;
}

#navbar{
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
color:white;
font-size: 80px;
font-style: bold;
display: block;
margin: 60px auto;

}

<body>
<div class="left">
<div id="logo">
<img src="/pictures/logo.png">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS for ID `logoimage` is not being applied to anything. You have an img element, but it has no ID specified. Change `<img src="/pictures/logo.png">` to `<img id="logoimage" src="/pictures/logo.png" />` for it to take effect.

Also, there's no point setting `width` to 100% AND `max-width` to 100%. It's redundant. Either set width to 100% to ensure the element is 100% width, *or* set max-width to 100% ensuring the element will auto-width *up to* a maximum of 100%.